# How can I get title & scripts inside a webpage using webkit + gtk?

Tags: python, webkit, gtk

Here 's my code snippet

```
import gtk, webkit
window = gtk.Window()
browser = webkit.WebView()
url = "www.google.com"
browser.open(url)
```

Now I wanna get the web page title, script tags inside. So how can I do that ?

The documentation is not clear at these points and I only found documentation for Objective-C and I am trying to find my way there. Please if you know where can I get a better reference not necessarily for Python. C, C++ would be fine also.

Thanks

Comment: The C documentation can be found at http://webkitgtk.org and there is a Python HOWTO at http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work (I can't try it out right now):

```
def title_changed(widget, frame, title):
    print title

browser.connect('title-changed', title_changed)
```

There is some documentation [here](http://www.aclevername.com/articles/python-webgui/) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/wiki/HowDoI) and two examples in the demo directory from the source tarball.

Answer (score 0):

It is not bound to the technology used to retrieve the html. Once browser has opened it, just parse the html with beautiful soup or anything that supports XPath for example.